# Select n random rows per group in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Can I somehow combine these two queries into one in MySQL 5.7 without global variables and stored procedures?

```
define p1_id, p2_id int;

...

insert into Cards_in_game_decks select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=p1_id order by rand() limit 10;
insert into Cards_in_game_decks select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=p2_id order by rand() limit 10;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do a union:

```
insert into Cards_in_game_decks select * from (
  (select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=p1_id order by rand() limit 10)
  union all
  (select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=p2_id order by rand() limit 10)
) random_cards
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1gxffAcC)

To get up to 10 cards per player for up to 6 players listed in a Players table, you just have to get repetitive:

```
insert into Cards_in_game_decks select * from (
  (select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=(select id from Players where game_id=1 order by id limit 0,1) order by rand() limit 10)
  union all
  (select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=(select id from Players where game_id=1 order by id limit 1,1) order by rand() limit 10)
  union all
  (select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=(select id from Players where game_id=1 order by id limit 2,1) order by rand() limit 10)
  union all
  (select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=(select id from Players where game_id=1 order by id limit 3,1) order by rand() limit 10)
  union all
  (select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=(select id from Players where game_id=1 order by id limit 4,1) order by rand() limit 10)
  union all
  (select * from Cards_in_decks where Cards_in_decks.player_id=(select id from Players where game_id=1 order by id limit 5,1) order by rand() limit 10)
) random_cards
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_tvK_i1H)

There are likely much better ways to do this in mysql 8.

Comment: But is it possible to do it without uniton? I can take players ids from 
```SELECT id from Players where Players.game_id=game_id```
, where game_id is a procedure argument. In your case I have to make union for each player, which is not very convinient

Comment: why do you want to do it without a union?  you need the union if you want to get no more than 10 cards per player

Comment: oh, I see what you mean.  how many players can there be in a game?

Comment: In my case it will be 2-6 players

Comment: This looks extremely heavy in terms of performance, given that the `ORDER BY rand()` is computed n times. Is there a way you can think of to carry out this task using that clause only once?

Comment: So there's no other way to iterate thrugh each player in 5.7, I see...

Comment: Not and get 10 cards for each in 5.7

Comment: The order by rand is just on one players cards at a time, not likely to be that bad

Comment: This will only happen once per game, so I don't think it will be a burden on the server